# Error when getting tensor from the model: Variable batch_normalization_1_3/moving_mean/biased already exists, disallowed

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Keras, TF backend. I've loaded my pretrained model and I need to get a Tensor from one of intermediate layres for further use Deep Explain package

```
model = load_model(path_to_model)
input_tensor = model.layers[0].input
fModel = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=model.layers[-2].output)
target_tensor = fModel(input_tensor)
```

I've got error in the last line

```
Variable batch_normalization_1_3/moving_mean/biased already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

This problem appears only in jupyter notebook, or when I'm using GPU.

Comment: Which line does it error? Can you provide the trace? I'm guessing it is the final line and it is trying to reconstruct model.

Comment: Yes, it appears on the last line. Full trace extreamly long, I can post to pastebin.  So, how to solve it, and why it successfully works without jupyter on cpu?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comment, the error occurs because you are calling the `fModel` on the `input_tensor` a second time on the last line. So it tries to build the model starting from `input_tensor`. But wait, you already did that in the previous line.

You can call `fModel.predict` if you want to *run* the network on NumPy arrays. But the last line serves no purpose.

Comment: No. I'm need the target_tensor with keras Tensor type (not an Numpy array). Penult line constract the model, and last line produce this tensor. (see  https://github.com/marcoancona/DeepExplain/blob/master/examples/mint_cnn_keras.ipynb)